# mongoDB geospatial '$near' operator for Polygon

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

I have this format of data in my collection:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53563136d91216a097fc4e12"),
    "type" : "Feature",
    "geometry" : {
        "type" : "LineString",
        "coordinates" : [
            [13468472.06, 1625377.26],
            [13468446.27, 1625383.95], 
            [13468425.24, 1625398.28], 
            [13468396.58, 1625419.29]
        ]
    }
}
```

When perform this query:

```js
db.foobar.find({ 
    "geometry":{ 
        "$near": { 
            "$geometry": { 
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates" : [13468472, 1625377] 
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Why don't I get the results? and how do I perform the query when I want to know what specific points belong to that LineString?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, as of now, you cannot perform the queries of '$near' operator on anything other than 'Point' type geometries. This is why you are not getting the results.

If you wish to see a demonstration of $near, you can try creating a collection of points - index it - and then run the query.

One useful video link i found to see $near in action is [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a1tc0tPY7oE). The video is not a very recent one but is still good.